# Bitcoin Country of origin analysis

Tags: technical-analysis

I would like to analyze bitcoin transactions based on the origin by country.

Is there a API or program (maybe like Datasploit, only the other way around) to cross reverence location and transactions. I prefer python to analyze but of course all input is welcome on tools used and reliability of the analytics.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Location is not a detail recorded in transactions.  Specific Exchanges *might* record the IP address or location where their clients are located at the time they make a transaction, however that is clearly only going to be a small portion of the overall chain of transactions.

Comment: and against the idea of privacy in bitcoin :-)